# max age must be greater than min age by using jquery

Tags: php

[image]
my code is written below. age group age from must be equal to or less than age to please help

```
<select name="age_from" class="form-control">
    <option value="18"
        @if(old('age_from'))
            {{ old('age_from') }} 
        @else 
            18 
        @endif
    >
        @if(old('age_from'))
            {{ old('age_from') }} 
        @else 18 @endif
    </option>
        @for($i=19;$i<=65;$i++)

            <option>{{$i}}</option> 
        @endfor
</select>


<select name="age_to" class="form-control">
    @for($i=18;$i<65;$i++)
        <option>{{$i}}</option> 
    @endfor
        <option selected>
            @if(old('age_to')) 
                 {{ old('age_to') }}
            @else 
                 65+ 
            @endif
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Title says jQuery, tag says PHP, code looks like neither. Which is it?

Comment: Redefine your question clearly and provide more background on this.

Comment: I am doing this in PHP larval .want to use jquery for validating age.

Comment: why are you calculating all this in html just calculate array in controller and  just pass array here. in blade.php file and looping it. no need to use these condition in blade.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".age_to").change(function(){

```
     var age_from =$('.age_from').val();
        var age_to =$('.age_to').val();
     if(age_from > age_to ){
         $('.age_to').css('border-color', 'red');
         $('.age_warrning').show();
     }else{
         $('.age_to').css('border-color', '');
         $('.age_warrning').hide();
         }
        });
 $(".age_from").change(function(){

     var age_from =$('.age_from').val();
        var age_to =$('.age_to').val();
     if(age_from > age_to ){
         $('.age_to').css('border-color', 'red');
         $('.age_warrning').show();
     }else{
         $('.age_to').css('border-color', '');
         $('.age_warrning').hide();
         }
        });
    });
```